# How to emit to room in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How can I emit a request from a server to the client, to only one client...

I know that `io.sockets.to(room).emit('event' data)` exists, but I don't hear about `socket.to(room).emit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are namespaces and rooms in socket.io. You can join every user to unique room with `.join` and send event to that room with `socket.to(room).emit`. How to do that read here
http://socket.io/#how-to-use
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

or

```
var io = io.listen(server);
io.clients[sessionID].send()
```